# Updating Angular Directives in Another Controller Scope After Pushing Breeze Entity

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm building an `Angular SPA` with `Breeze` and `TypeScript`.

Problem is I'm using `newsequentialid()` on the table key columns in `SQL Server` so I can't create an entity with `Breeze` (or `LINQ` to `EF`) without first having the row ID already generated.

On the client side, I'm posting new entity data with `$http.post` to the `Web API` which calls a `stored procedure` in `SQL server` that returns the new ID with OUTPUT `inserted.Id`. The `Web API` then returns the newly created sequential ID back to the `Angular app`, updating the new `Breeze` entity's ID. I then have to push the new `Breeze entity` onto an existing `Array of Breeze entities`.

I have `directives` with isolate scopes (2-way binding with reference types) that all update calculations based on values in shared dependencies among many angular `controller` modules on a page. Many `controllers` share the state of an `array of Breeze entities`, particularly payroll rows. The `directives` must show aggregate calculations of these rows and update when payroll items are created, deleted, or updated.  When I change a value in a row field, all of the `directive` calculations update properly. But I can't get the calculations to update when I add or delete a `Breeze` entity to/from the `shared array`. Is there something about the `Breeze` framework I'm missing that would trigger the `directives` to update when adding/deleting? I don't want to rely on `$broadcast` or `$emit` - that would seem to be an anti-pattern and become very repetitious throughout the app. Thank you.

This is my method for creating a new employee budget item in the database. The Web API returns a new sequential ID which is used to set the value of the Breeze entity's primary key.

```
createEmployeeBudget(employeeBudget: IEmployeeBudget, employeeBudgets: Array<IEmployeeBudget>): void {
            this.$http.post(this.config.remoteServiceName + EmployeeBudget.getApiCreateMethod(), JSON.stringify(employeeBudget)).then(
                (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Response<string>>): void => {
                    var data = response.data;

                    if (data.error != null) {
                        this.logError(data.error);

                    } else {
                        var newId = data.data; //new sequential Guid from Web API
                        employeeBudget.EmployeeBudgetId = newId; //add new sequential ID to entity

                        var entity = this.manager.createEntity(EmployeeBudget.getType(), employeeBudget); //create the entity the Breeze way
                        employeeBudgets.push(<any>this.manager.addEntity(entity)); //push Breeze entity onto exsisting array of Breeze entities

                        this.logSuccess("Added new " + EmployeeBudget.getDisplayName() + ".");
                    }
                });
        }

    // a formula directive
    app.directive('budgetBalance', ['formulas', function (formulas: Services.IFormulaService) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    services: '=services',
                    budget: '=budget',
                    benefits: '=employeeBenefits',
                    ess: '=employerSupportServices',
                    emps: '=employeeBudgets'
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attr): void {
                    scope.$watch(function (scope) {
                        scope.total = formulas.getBudgetBalance(scope.services, scope.budget, scope.benefits, scope.ess, scope.emps);
                    });
                }
                , template: '{{total | currency}}'
            };
        }]);
```

Comment: Seems like you should be able to create your newsequentialid on the server in the BeforeSaveEntities function, and assign them to the entities on the server right before they are saved.

Comment: Did you try calling scope.$apply() after adding to the array?

Comment: Thank you but that throws a `$digest already in progress` error. The function in my directives are added with `scope.$watch(function(){/*return value*/});` I've updated my post with one of these directives.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. My problem wasn't a Breeze problem but an Angular scoping problem. I have a parent view with many child `ui-views`. I need to share common dependencies among all of the child controllers via UI Router's dependency injection. After failing to update the scope of arrays in sibling controllers, I tried just injecting the dependencies into the parent shell controller and inheriting the parent scope's variables in all child controllers and directives.

It worked! Now I can guarantee all child controllers and directives are sharing and watching the same references. It isn't the ideal state of Dependency Injection I was aiming for. It's a rather small but necessary compromise in this context.

This is a simplified version of views and controllers. I have about 8 arrays of complex entities I'm sharing among all child controllers.

The UI Router `state` declaration

```
$stateProvider
    .state('budget', {
        url: '/budget/:budgetId',
        templateUrl: "/app/budget/budgetshell.html",
        controller: Controllers.BudgetShellController.Id,
        controllerAs: "vm",
        // Dependencies - these are Promises
        resolve: {
            budget: ['$stateParams', 'datacontext', function ($stateParams: IAppStateParams, datacontext: Services.IDatacontext) {
                return datacontext.getBudget($stateParams.budgetId);
            }],
            employeeBudgetItems: ['$stateParams', 'datacontext', function ($stateParams: IAppStateParams, datacontext: Services.IDatacontext) {
                return datacontext.getEmployeeBudgets($stateParams.budgetId);
            }]
        },  
        // child views
        views: {
            'budget@budget': Views.budget,
            'employeebudgets@budget': Views.employeeBudgets,
            'budgettotals@budget': Views.budgetTotals
        }
    });
```

My controller HTML template with ui-views:

```
<div>
    <div ui-view="budget"></div>

    <!-- more child ui-views are here -->

    <!-- Budget Totals/Payroll Expense and Breakdown Totals -->
    <div ui-view="budgettotals"></div>
</div>
```

Dependencies are injected into `BudgetShellController` which publicly shares them with its child controllers and directives.

```
module App.Controllers {
    export interface IBudgetShellController {
        budget: IBudget;
        employeeBudgetItems: Array<IEmployeeBudget>;
        /* more dependencies here */
    }

    export class BudgetShellController implements IBudgetShellController {  
        static Id: string = 'budgetShellController';

        // public dependencies accessible by child controllers and directives
        public budget: IBudget;
        public employeeBudgetItems: Array<IEmployeeBudget>;

        // inject dependencies from data service
        static $inject = ['budget', 'employeeBudgetItems'];
        constructor(budget: IBudget, employeeBudgetItems: Array<IEmployeeBudget>){
            this.budget = budget;
            this.employeeBudgetItems = employeeBudgetItems;
        }
   }

    app.controller(BudgetShellController.Id, BudgetShellController);
}
```

A child controller with directives that calculate totals for the parent controller's scope variables:

```
module App.Controllers {

    export class BudgetTotalsController {   
        static Id: string = 'budgetTotalsController';   
        private budget: IBudget;
        private employeeBudgetItems: Array<IEmployeeBudget>;

        static $inject = ['$scope'];
        constructor(private $scope: any)
        {
            // reference parent scope variables
            // totals always update when adding/deleting from arrays
            var parent = <IBudgetShellController>$scope.$parent.vm;
            this.budget = parent.budget;         
            this.employeeBudgetItems = parent.employeeBudgetItems;
        }
    }

    app.controller(BudgetTotalsController.Id, BudgetTotalsController);
}
```